# Laravel 4: how to write the correct nested controller for nested resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, restful-url

In Laravel 4, I wish to create a set of restful resources as follows:

```
http://localhost/posts/1/comments   
http://localhost/posts/1/comments/1 
http://localhost/posts/1/comments/1/edit
```

...
So I created two controllers: **PostsController** and **CommentsController** (on the same layer), and the routes are written as below:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

I also created a link in /views/comments/index.blade.php referring to routes: posts.comments.create

```
{{ link_to_route('posts.comments.create', 'Add new comment') }}
```

Here's the problem I met:

When I visit `http://localhost/posts/1/comments`, the page throws **MissingMandatoryParametersException**, indicating:

*Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts") to generate a URL for route "posts.comments.create".*

How can I fix the problem, and how can I know whether the solution also applies for the create and edit methods in CommentsController?

e.g.

```
 public function index()
{
    $tasks = $this->comment->all();

    return View::make('comments.index', compact('comments'));

}

public function create()
    {
       return View::make('comments.create');

    }

public function show($post_id,$comment_id)  
    {  
        $comment = $this->comment->findOrFail($comment_id);  

        return View::make('comments.show', compact('comment'));  

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using nested controllers in two projects, love them. The problem seems to be in your controller and route link.

In the CommentsController, the $post_id is missing. Do something like this:

```
public function create($post_id)
{
   return View::make('comments.create')
    ->with('post_id', $post_id);
}
```

When creating links to a nested controller, the ID's of all of the ancestors must be provided. In this case the $post_id is again missing. You may have to make it available to your view if it's not already.

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('posts.comments.create', 'Add new comment', $post_id) }}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got another issues when writing a redirect::route as below:  `return Redirect::route('posts.comments.create')->with('post_id',$post_id)
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');`   It still throw the same exception,anything wrong?