# Laravel 4 resource controller show($id) method problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Does it have to be the **'id'** column in database table which works fine for 
show($id), edit($id) method in controller?
I want to replace **$id** with the value of '**post_id**' column in database table, but it throws error: `ModelNotFoundException`
How can I fix it?

sample code:

database table:

> id(int), post_id(varchar32), post_title(varchar32), post_content(text)

routes:

> Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

PostsController:

> public function show($id) 
>       {
>           return View::make('posts.show');
>       }

When I visit `http://localhost/posts/1`
it should return the view of post which has **id** 1 in the table.
What if I what to return the view based on **post_id** value in the table?
Does it have to replace the parameter in show() or ?

Comment: can you please add relevant code ?

Comment: sure, added as above.

Comment: You're not really using the $id, you're just rendering the view in show method. And yes, you can pass whatever you need, your links just have to be in conformity with the resource: route.show must be `http://host/route_name/id-or-anything-else`. But if you are getting ModelNotFoundException is because FindOrFail or FirstOrFail is being used somewhere else in your code. I don't see them being used in Laravel source code, they must be yours.

Comment: Thank you!It turns out that the FindOrFail($id) will look for the primary key in table.In my case, I can solve the problem either by setting post_id as primary key or use where () to retrieve the post. Can you please have a look at another problems related to nested controller? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633898/laravel-4-how-to-write-the-correct-nested-controller-for-nested-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PostsController you need to access the Post model to get the data from the db.

like this:
    //PostsController

```
public function show($id) { 
$post = Post::where('post_id', $id)->first();

return View::make('posts.show', compact('post')); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!I also find it since laravel set id as the default primary column, i may also manually define post_id as the primary key in model, though not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use find

```
public function show($id) { 
$post = Post::find($id);
return View::make('posts.show', compact('post')); 
}
```